# Is it possible to create a grid layout in a list?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

*disclaimer*: I'm just learning vue.js and vuetify and I'm not very familiar with javascript. I'm writing my first vue.js app.

I'm using vue 2.x and vuetify 2.x.

I need to create a scrolable list of items on which the user will be able to perform actions. For now, I'm just concerned about the layout of the list items.

The item is made of two visible information, a number and a text (like an inventory) that should be displayed in two columns. The numbers should be right aligned in their column and the text left aligned.

This is what I have so far.

```
<template>
  <v-list dense>
    <template v-for="(item, index) in items">
      <v-list-item :key="item.r">
        <v-list-item-content class="font-weight-bold">
          <v-list-item-title> 
            {{ item.n }} {{ item.t }}
          </v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
      <v-divider :key="index"></v-divider>
    </template>
  </v-list>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "itemList",
  data() {
    return {
      items: this.$store.state.currentItems,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Is it possible to use a layout inside a list item ? If not, how could I create the desired column alignment ?

In case it could influence the implementation, the actions are

- make the item a sliding button with multiple selectable actions
- or make the number and the text individual clickable flat buttons with popup menus
- manually reorder list items with drag and drop.

An alternative to the sliding button (if not possible) is to make the number and text flat buttons with a popup menu. I guess this could influence how to define the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generally with the use of `v-row` and `v-col` you can implement a layout and this is true inside of a `v-list-item-content`, for example check the code below (I'm not sure if I understood the layout you've asked for correctly or not but it must give you a hint)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    items: [{
        t: 'title one',
        n: 1
      },
      {
        t: 'title two',
        n: 2
      },
      {
        t: 'title three',
        n: 3
      },
      {
        t: 'title four',
        n: 4
      },
    ],
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-list dense>
          <template v-for="(item, index) in items">
            <v-list-item :key="item.n">
              <v-list-item-content class="font-weight-bold">
                <v-row>
                  <v-col cols="6">
                    <v-row no-gutters justify="end">{{ item.n }}</v-row>
                  </v-col>
                  
                  <v-col cols="6">
                    <v-row no-gutters>{{ item.t }}</v-row>
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-divider :key="`divider-${item.n}`"></v-divider>
          </template>
        </v-list>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I just changed the cols="6" but that's a detail. What I don't understand is the keys. The code I gave above gives a warning for each displayed item. It say that there are duplicate keys. item.r is a unique key (primary key in database language). It's not item.n which is the numeric value. What I don't understand is the `:key="`divider-${item.n}`"`in the v-divider. Why doing that ?

Comment: in vuejs whenever you use v-for you should use an unique key for each element in the loop so the vue knows exactly which element is which, particularly this is important for rendering, without an unique key you might run into weird bugs specially when clicking an element should do something.  about the error, the primary key might be an `int` and in your code divider uses array index as key which is also an `int` and you might get two int `1` as key and hence the error. by doing what I did for the divider key I just made sure I'm avoiding the duplicate key error. (divider-1, divider-2, ...)

Comment: That explains it. Indeed, the item.r value is the same as the index value by coincidence. Thank you very much. This solves another problem I had.

Comment: glad it helped ;)